In x25519kyber768 what is the use of the server kyber keys if only the client public kyber key is used for encapsulation in kem?
In x25519kyber768 what is the use of the server kyber keys if only the client public kyber key is used for encapsulation of the kyber shared secret in kem?

There is no server side key pair for x25519kyber768.
Observe this diagram from a medium blog on the exchange

Note that the client side generates key pairs for x25519 and kyber768 while the server side only generates a pair for x25519.

Thanks I saw this already. I wanted to confirm. I saw that In this reddit thread thread it said that the server and the client both generate their kyber and 25519 key pairs. So was confused. https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/15qq9o6/x25519kyber768/
